# How to set Visual Studio Code Terminal output to English

Tags: visual-studio-code

My environment is:

- Visual Studio Code: English
- Windows 10: Japanese

When I try to use Terminal to add package, it output messages in Japanese.
But I would like it to output them in English.

[image: terminal output]

[image]

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution.
Because the terminal uses PowerShell, we should set the powershell's output.
Here it is:

1. execute the command `"set-culture -cultureinfo en-US"` in terminal
2. restart vscode
3. execute "get-culture" in the terminal and confirm the output just like this:

---

```
LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
1033             en-US            英語 (米国)
```

Answer (score 2):

For Windows

1. go to **visual studio code**
2. Press Ctrl+Shift+P to bring up the Command Palette then start typing "display" 
   to filter and display the **Configure Display Language** command.
3. open **local.json** file
4. You can use IntelliSense (Ctrl+Space) to select a different supported language locale.
5. Change to **en**
6. **Restart** Visual Studio Code

Comment: local.json do has been setted  en

Comment: it means your visual studio code does not have English language package. 
you have to install English Language Package.

Comment: I have install english language package today, and it still not works.

Comment: after installing language follow the steps given in answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. After installing language, and have confirmed it is stetted "en", and restart vscode. But still not work

Answer (score 1):

**For ubuntu / Linux**

Edit two files:

1. `sudoedit /etc/default/locale`

   ```
   LANG="en_US"

   LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
   ```
2. `sudoedit ~/.pam_environment`

   ```
   LANG=en_US

   LANGUAGE=en_US
   ```

**Logout and Login or Reboot.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'm using vs code in win10. so I have no idea where are they

Answer (score 0):

I'm on linux but having the same problem.

What works for me is to check `terminal > integrated: inherit env` in vscode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I found the solution here https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/8686

It was fixed by setting the environmental variable "DOTNET_CLI_UI_LANGUAGE" to "en"