# My vscode is part English part Chinese, how to change it to complete English?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As mentioned in the title, I have part of my vscode Chinese, which is troublesome since looking up error codes in English will be easier. How can I turn it into complete English? I've tried [How to set Visual Studio Code Terminal output to English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508152/how-to-set-visual-studio-code-terminal-output-to-english) and it didn't work for me.

[image: my vscode output is Chinese]

Since someone asked for the code to be post in text, this is the code (I'm using a tutorial code for camera calibration from opencv, so the error code appearing also confused me):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  (void)argc;
  (void)argv;

  std::vector<cv::String> fileNames;
  cv::glob("../calibration/Image*.png", fileNames, false);
  cv::Size patternSize(25 - 1, 18 - 1);
  std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> q(fileNames.size());

  std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point3f>> Q;
  // 1. Generate checkerboard (world) coordinates Q. The board has 25 x 18
  // fields with a size of 15x15mm

  int checkerBoard[2] = {25,18};
  // Defining the world coordinates for 3D points
    std::vector<cv::Point3f> objp;
    for(int i = 1; i<checkerBoard[1]; i++){
      for(int j = 1; j<checkerBoard[0]; j++){
        objp.push_back(cv::Point3f(j,i,0));
      }
    }

  std::vector<cv::Point2f> imgPoint;
  // Detect feature points
  std::size_t i = 0;
  for (auto const &f : fileNames) {
    std::cout << std::string(f) << std::endl;

    // 2. Read in the image an call cv::findChessboardCorners()
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(fileNames[i]);
    cv::Mat gray;

    cv::cvtColor(img, gray, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

    bool patternFound = cv::findChessboardCorners(gray, patternSize, q[i], cv::CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv::CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE + cv::CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK);

    // 2. Use cv::cornerSubPix() to refine the found corner detections
    if(patternFound){
        cv::cornerSubPix(gray, q[i],cv::Size(11,11), cv::Size(-1,-1), cv::TermCriteria(cv::TermCriteria::EPS + cv::TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, 30, 0.1));
        Q.push_back(objp);
    }

    // Display
    cv::drawChessboardCorners(img, patternSize, q[i], patternFound);
    cv::imshow("chessboard detection", img);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    i++;
  }


  cv::Matx33f K(cv::Matx33f::eye());  // intrinsic camera matrix
  cv::Vec<float, 5> k(0, 0, 0, 0, 0); // distortion coefficients

  std::vector<cv::Mat> rvecs, tvecs;
  std::vector<double> stdIntrinsics, stdExtrinsics, perViewErrors;
  int flags = cv::CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO + cv::CALIB_FIX_K3 +
              cv::CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST + cv::CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT;
  cv::Size frameSize(1440, 1080);

  std::cout << "Calibrating..." << std::endl;
  // 4. Call "float error = cv::calibrateCamera()" with the input coordinates
  // and output parameters as declared above...

  float error = cv::calibrateCamera(Q, q, frameSize, K, k, rvecs, tvecs, flags);

  std::cout << "Reprojection error = " << error << "\nK =\n"
            << K << "\nk=\n"
            << k << std::endl;

  // Precompute lens correction interpolation
  cv::Mat mapX, mapY;
  cv::initUndistortRectifyMap(K, k, cv::Matx33f::eye(), K, frameSize, CV_32FC1,
                              mapX, mapY);

  // Show lens corrected images
  for (auto const &f : fileNames) {
    std::cout << std::string(f) << std::endl;

    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(f, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);

    cv::Mat imgUndistorted;
    // 5. Remap the image using the precomputed interpolation maps.
    cv::remap(img, imgUndistorted, mapX, mapY, cv::INTER_LINEAR);

    // Display
    cv::imshow("undistorted image", imgUndistorted);
    cv::waitKey(0);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @brian2lee please send your code as text in your post. Don't send code as image. If you send your code as text it can help to other people help you easy and quick.

Comment: I'm sending pic cuz I just want to show the part chinese problem as mention, though the code error I'm trying to solve also bothers me, it isn't the question I'm asking in this thread. However I can send the code in the pic too.

Comment: @AliNajafZadeh I've edit the question, you should able to see the code in text now.

Comment: Looks like the output of your terminal is chinese. What have you tried to resolve that? Where are you stuck?

Comment: More specifically, Visual Studio (not Visual Studio Code!) appears to be installed in Chinese. I think there's a language configuration menu somewhere in their installation dialog.

Comment: @NicoHaase  "output of my terminal is chinese" is what I'm trying to resolve now. Otherwise I'll have to stick with this painful chinese error code from now on.

Comment: @skink but im using vscode not vs, and if i installed it in chinese wouldn't it be all chinese?

Comment: Yep, you're _writing_ code in VSCode (it's only an editor), but VS is being used to compile the code -- that's the part that is in Chinese.

Comment: @skink then how do i turn it English, I don't even know what vs it's using.

Comment: @skink I found out the vs it's using and install a new one (Blend for Visual Studio 2022) (which clears some of my error, apperantly the error occur cuz I'm using an very old ver vs). However, after setting up the english vs and select the kit in vsc, it still shows chinese.

Answer (score 0):

check this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/82791

actually this issue not only occurs in cpp, it is because some extensions use your system language (like java support extensions), it can only be solved case by case

as for me, i just deleted all unneeded language pack in extensions (not for vscode but in each extension folder)