# Change VSCode formatting from scanner.nextDouble(); from <,> to <.> by default

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, java.util.scanner

Change VSCode formatting from scanner.nextDouble(); from <,> to <.> by default

When using the scanner.nextDouble(); method, the VSCode Terminal only accepts <,> instead of the normal <.> for decimal points. Already tried changing the VSCode locale to English.

Comment: What is the locale on System level?

Comment: This works fine on my machine. Please show more details about your setup and environment.       Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Hulk thank you for the help! My problem got solved by the related question you sent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Visual Studio Code Terminal output to English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508152/how-to-set-visual-studio-code-terminal-output-to-english)

Comment: Glad to hear that - in that case, it can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the command "set-culture -cultureinfo en-US" in the terminal. As seen in the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508152/how-to-set-visual-studio-code-terminal-output-to-english), suggested by @Hulk